# Illegal strings logcat at eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, logcat

I have several devices. First (phone) worked correct. I see in eclipse tab logcat normal strings. On second device (Cube U30GT2), I don't know why, but see that logcat string divided on two: date/tag and messages.

[image]

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue, that I use don't last ADT. Now we use in group 17 version. Try with another sdk (20), all ok.

Comment: But actually you you will continue to receive such messages, as shown in the log Cat GC work.

Comment: Ofcouse :), but my issue was spliting strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is no error. You're app eating recources and GC worked. It's normally. That's happens on Android 3+.

Comment: Yes, I'm understood, that this is not error. But I want correct strings in one strings.